# How to assign two objects with both having key variables

Tags: javascript, object

```
function updateObjectWithKeyAndValue (object, key, value) {
    object = { [key]: value };
    let new_object = {[key] : value};
    return Object.assign(object, new_object);
}
```

**Error:**

Objects `updateObjectWithKeyAndValue(object, key, value)` returns an object with the original key value pairs and the new key value pair:
     Error: Expected `{ prop2: 2 }` to match `{ prop: 1, prop2: 2 }`

Comment: pls elaborate more

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? The code you provided does not really make much sense. Please try to describe in detail what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry..I'm trying to create a function, that returns an object that contains two key value pairs. an original pair and a new key value pair without modifying the original but uses a clone.

Comment: The test provide variables that becomes the key and value. But when I use square notations '[key]' ,because I want the test to insert the variable. The second [key] variable overwrites the first one "Expected { prop2: 2 } to match { prop: 1, prop2: 2 }"

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function to update provided object with specific key and value, you just need this:

```
function updateObjectWithKeyAndValue (object, key, value) {
  if (typeof object === 'object' && object !== null) {
    object[key] = value;
  }
}
```